# The difference between ‘The later train’ and ‘The next train’

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The next train will also get you to work on time.

Can I replace the ‘next’ with ‘later’ ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. If you are discussing which train you should take, the choice might be between the **next** train and the **later** train.

> You can take the next train, but the later train will also get you to work on time.

But if the you have missed a train, then

> The next train will get you to work on time.

and the following sentence doesn't work well

> The later train will get you to work on time.

because in this case there is nothing for "later" to compare with.

Answer (score -2):

> The next train.

Mean the train just after the actual one.

> The later train.

Mean the last one, so you probably have to wait like 11 pm in order to take it.
*note: it would even be better to say "The last train."*

---

**Conclusion:**

In the sentence

> The next train will also get you to work on time.

No, you cannot replace the ‘next’ with ‘later’, otherwise this will completely change the meaning of the sentence